# Using Symfony2, how to get ajax post data from the request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, symfony, jquery-file-upload

I want to upload a file with jquery-file-upload (blueimp) with some data in cross domain.

So in client side I use the code from basic.html file from jqueryfileupload. I just added  forceIframeTransport for cross domain (doc [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads))& formData (for format type doc [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#formdata)).

```
var idResp = {name:'id-resp',value: SLjQuery('#media_answer_answer').data('id-resp')};
var dataSup = $('form#answer_process_form').serializeArray();
dataSup.push(idResp);

$(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#media_answer_answer').fileupload({
        url: "mywebsite.dev/app_dev.php/api/media/questionnaire-test-media/uploads",
        dataType: 'json',
        formData: dataSup,
        forceIframeTransport: true,
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log('upload ok ', data);
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
             console.log(data.loaded/data.total);
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
      .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled')
    ;
    $('#media_answer_answer').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        'mywebsite.dev/result.html?%s'
    );
});
```

When I select a file by the input, into the console, the log of progressall is to 1. So it seems to be sending. Moreover I can see in the network tab in the console the request sent

```
//in request headers
Content-Length: 43463
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvU5EBWuRkyGkSRBS
...
//in request payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryvU5EBWuRkyGkSRBS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_answer[_token]"

e6583ea5230f1f80a218825ed399115925556f0c
------WebKitFormBoundary1JHxUF9xgtcO5fJ2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id-resp"

420
------WebKitFormBoundaryvU5EBWuRkyGkSRBS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_answer[answer]"; filename="file-to-upload.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryvU5EBWuRkyGkSRBS--

//in response headers
...
X-ChromeLogger-Data: eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiNC4wIiwiY29sdW1.... // I think this is the file in base64
...
```

Now in server side, I use FosRestBundle for routing. In my symfony controller I want to get the data and the file.

```
//result of request
POST /app_dev.php/api/media/questionnaire-test-media/uploads  HTTP/1.1 
Accept:          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
...
Content-Length:  43463 
Content-Type:    multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBqSBpxJ6Wyvi2QJH
```

So content-length is 43463 so I think there is something, but in the controller `$request->getContent()` is empty and `$request->request->all()` too.

Do you know if data are sended ? if yes, how to get data present in payload ? thanks a lot and happy new year

Comment: did you try `$request->files`?

Comment: @xurshid29 yes, but logger doesn't show anything for `$request->files`, `$request->files->get('media_answer[answer]')` shows empty.

Comment: I tried `$logger->info($request->files->get('media_answer[answer]', array(), true));` I can see the temp path where file is uploaded ex:  `/tmp/phpf4OVQP`. With `watch ls` in /tmp I saw a short time the file. So why I can't get it from request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the logger of symfony doesn't show me anything on `$request->request->all()` , but in preview tab in console I could see some var_dump on `$request->request->all()`  and it wasn't empty (I want to swear myself), it contains the 2 first data of request payload (content-disposition form-data), but not the last one (Content-Type: image/jpeg).

I had to change the 2nd data to become

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvU5EBWuRkyGkSRBS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_answer[idResp]"

420
```

Then in the controller I can get the data like this :

```
$r = $request->request->all(); // or using $request->getContent() it's also possible in a different way
$rt = $r['media_answer']['_token']; // e6583ea5230f1f80a218825ed399115925556f0c
$ri = $r['media_answer']['id-resp']; // 420
```

For the last data : `name="media_answer[answer]" filename="file-to-upload.jpg"`
As I said in the comments above I can get the file like this :

```
$request->files->get('media_answer[answer]', array(), true)
```

So for the filename :

```
$request->files->get('media_answer[answer]', array(), true)->getClientOriginalName()
```